# Проблема с кодировкой JS-файла

Tags: javascript, кодировка

пишу скрипт для себя, но столкнулся с проблемой отображения кириллических символов в браузере Google Chrome. Выглядит примерно следующим образом

[image: Просмотр JS-файла в браузере]

Пробовал просмотреть тот же файл через другие браузеры. К примеру, Edge все отображает корректно, без кракозябр. Решил любопытства ради поискать кириллицу на других сайтах в JS через Google Chrome, к моему удивлению у людей там все нормально отображается. Не могу понять, что я делаю не так.

P.S. Для писанины использую Sublime Text 3, кодировка файла - UTF-8 без BOM. HTML и CSS файлы отображают кириллицу корректно, проблема только в JS

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` не пробовали?

Comment: Вы открываете локальный файл или сайт? На сайте кодировка известна из HTTP-заголовков, а при открытии локального файла кодировку узнать неоткуда (а отображающий Edge скорее всего нарушает стандарты)

Comment: Sublihim, проблема в js-файле, не в html, я же написал

Comment: andreymal, открываю через localhost, сервак питоновский. Запускаю через cmd (python -m http.server)

Comment: @Chamond в таком случае питоновский сервак тоже не знает кодировок файлов и не указывает их в HTTP-заголовках. (Можно ли указать, я не в курсе)

Answer (score 3):

Если смотреть на **Apache**

Просто запрос файла .js без страницы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавим правильный заголовок

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Content-Type "application/javascript; charset=UTF-8"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По идее так и должно быть.

PS ( или AddCharset utf-8 .js );

Comment: можете объяснить, куда это добавить?

Comment: У Apache это httpd.conf или .htaccess, ищите документацию к вашему серверу